# all permutations from 2 lists but with a condition on the amount of elements

Tags: python, permutation

In Python I have :

```
a = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

I'm trying to build all possible permutations of 10 of these characters selected from list `a` or `b`, that would include *any* permutation containing:  **at least** 3 elements from `a` and **at least** 3 elements from `b`. The elements can be repeated, as they have been selected from the lists.

e.g, of valid permutations: `wa85ff3d56`, `333aaaaaaa`, `a33333aa33`

What's the most pythonic, efficient way of doing this?

PS: Yes, I know, The answer will be extremely large. It is expected. It will not be stored in memory, it will be streamed and used in live calculations.

For now, I generate all the possible combinaisons and then permutate them. However, the calculation will most definitely take months. I have this piece of code, which does the trick, but it's clearly not the most efficient way. Example for 3 from list `a` and 7 from list `b`, it generates `2.864429568e+14` permutations. So considering i'd have to do this 5 times `(3,7), (4,6), (5,5), (6,4), (7,3)`, I'd get a total of `1.432214784e+15` permutations. In comparison, without restrictions, there would be `36^10 = 3.65615844e+15`. So this method would remove almost half of the possible permutations.

```
import string
import itertools


a = list(string.digits)
b = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

a_combinaisons_3 = list(itertools.combinations(a, 3))
b_combinaisons_7 = list(itertools.combinations(b, 7))

a3b7_combinaisons = []

for a_element in a_combinaisons_3:
    for b_element in b_combinaisons_7:
        a3b7_combinaisons.append(a_element + b_element)

a3b7_permutations = list(itertools.permutations(a3b7_combinaisons))
print(len(a3b7_combinaisons))  # 78936000
print(len(a3b7_permutations))  # 1.432214784e+15
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing that worked yet. I'm wondering if someone has an idea to do this easily with itertools or some other tool. It's not a question about my specific work, I think this 
 is a general question. I'm still working on this right now, but I know I'll figure it out eventually with loops and if's, but I'm really interested in other people's ideas as well. Since there doesn't seem to be anything on the web about this yet, I figured I'd create the question :-)

Comment: Are you also repeating the values in each list to 3-7 characters or is it a true permutation of each list?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: @MarkM, not to be disrespectful, but I already read the docs of itertools. So, just copying the link doesn't really help.

Comment: In case you were wondering how *many* values you're looking to produce, it's a *big* number. Just the number of combinations (unordered) is: `10^3 * 26^3 * 36^4 = 29520930816000`. Are you sure you want them all?

Comment: @Woodford well, you don't have to store that all in memory but that is a pretty big number indeed

Comment: @Matiiss I know. I also don't have to write them all down on paper.

Comment: @PyThagoras To be honest I didn't fully grasp your question, and thought itertools.permutations would do the trick easily. But it doesn't. Apologies, I'll think about this some longer to see how I'd solve it.

Comment: @PyThagoras a good start is to find the amount of possible groups of size 10 from elements of the 2 lists subject the 3-3 condition. The permutation stuffs is secondary... you have itertools for that

Comment: Can you use `itertools` to write code that creates all the combinations of exactly 3 elements from `a` and exactly 7 elements from `b`? 4 and 6? etc.? If you have those, can you solve the problem?

Comment: Since your output suggests that repeats are allowed, you demonstrably *don't* mean permutations or combinations.

Comment: permutation of 10 character SELECTED from those 2 lists. not a permutation of the 2 lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to try to write a general-purpose answer here in the hope of having a good canonical target for duplicate questions in the future.

## Combinatoric Fundamentals in Python with `itertools`

### Reordering and Replacement (Repetition)

It's important to understand how the various [combinatoric iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) provided by `itertools` work and how they differ.

Let's consider a simple candidate set `A = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, from which we want to draw "combinations" (as question-askers will usually put it) of three elements.

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4]
```

`itertools.combinations` selects with no reordering (i.e., each output value will appear in the same order as in the input) and no repetition of the result values. This therefore produces only 4 results:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations(A, 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

`itertools.permutations` means that the results can appear in any order, i.e. a given subset of the input will appear multiple times in the output in different orders.

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations(A, 3)) # 24 results omitted for brevity
```

The four `combinations` appear in six orders each, for 24 total results.

`itertools.combinations_with_replacement` selects without reordering, but allows elements from the input to be chosen more than once:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(A, 3)) # 20 results omitted for brevity
```

There are four results where each element is chosen three times, six where a double is followed by a single (which must be higher), six where a single is followed by a double, plus the four `combinations` of all singles. Counting the results for this in the general case is not easy.

If you want to allow repetitions *and* reordering in your output results, you can use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> list(itertools.product(A, repeat=3)) # 64 results omitted for brevity
```

Simply, each of three times we freely choose from the four elements, for 4 * 4 * 4 = 64 results.

`itertools.product` implements what is called the [Cartesian product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CartesianProduct.html). In general, it pulls one element each from multiple specified sequences. But generating "permutations with replacement" is the same thing as pulling one element each from the same sequence multiple times, so the `repeat` keyword is offered as a convenient shortcut for this operation - so you don't have to specify the sequence multiple times. I mean, you *could* write `itertools.product(*[A]*3)`, but that's ugly.

### What about repetition in the candidate set?

This isn't related to OP's question as asked; but for completeness, it's important to understand that none of these functions care about elements of the candidate set being equal, or even identical:

```
>>> x = object()
>>> candidates = [x, x, x, x]
>>> results = list(itertools.combinations(candidates, 3))
>>> len(results)
4
>>> results[0] == results[1] == results[2] == results[3]
True
```

### How can we implement constraints?

The simplest way is to generate an inclusive result (in OP's case, by joining the `a` and `b` candidates together, and generating a `product` of 10 of those) and filter out things that don't meet the requirements. However, this is inefficient and can be ugly (we need to analyze an output tuple to figure out whether its elements meet the conditions - in OP's case, whether they were drawn from `a` or from `b`. If you do want to take an approach like this, I generally recommend writing a generator function:

```
def OP_problem():
    for result in itertools.product(a+b, repeat=10):
        a_count = len(x for x in result if x in a)
        # the trick is that every element was either from a or b;
        # so "at least 3 a's and at least 3 b's" is equivalent to
        # "at least 3 a's and at most 7 a's".
        if 3 <= a_count <= 7:
            yield result
```

or in simple enough cases, a generator expression:

```
(
    # maybe you don't think this is simple enough :)
    result for result in itertools.product(a+b, repeat=10)
    if 3 <= len(x for x in result if x in a) <= 7
)
```

Usually it's better to try to break the problem down into smaller pieces and put the results together. For example, the documentation has a recipe for computing [power sets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSet.html) that simply chains the results for combinations of 0 elements, 1 element etc. up to all the elements. (Another way is to find the cartesian product of N booleans, each representing whether or not to include a given element, and then translate them into subsets.)

In our case, we can separately find the results for each count of `a` elements. Let's consider the case of 5 elements from each list; it should be clear how to generalize that and combine the results (hint: use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, as shown in the `powerset` recipe in the documentation).

### Difficult cases: partitions and position selection

There's one advanced technique I want to showcase here, in order to solve the problem of selecting 5 elements from `a` and 5 elements from `b` and intermingling them. The idea is simply that we select *positions where the a's will go*, out of all the possible positions (i.e., indices into a sequence of 10 elements), and for each, generate the corresponding output results. Those positions are combinations without replacement (do you understand why?) of the possible index values.

Thus, something like:

```
def make_combination(letter_positions, chosen_letters, chosen_digits):
    result = [None] * 10
    for letter, position in zip(chosen_letters, letter_positions):
        result[position] = letter
    # Figure out where the digits go, using set arithmetic to find the
    # remaining positions, then putting them back in ascending order.
    digit_positions = sorted(set(range(10)) - set(chosen_letters))
    for digit, position in zip(chosen_digits, digit_positions):
        result[position] = digit
    assert None not in result
    return tuple(result)


def five_letters_and_five_digits():
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    digits = '0123456789'
    # It's not *easy*, but it's fairly elegant.
    # We separately generate the letter positions, letter selection
    # and digit selection, using `product` to get the cartesian product
    # of *those* possibilities; then for each of those, we translate
    # into a desired output - using `starmap` to iterate.
    return itertools.starmap(
        make_combination, 
        itertools.product(
            itertools.combinations(range(10), 5),
            itertools.product(letters, repeat=5),
            itertools.product(digits, repeat=5)
        )
    )
```

The technique of choosing positions is also useful for solving [partitioning](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Partition.html) problems. The idea is simply that you choose *positions where the partitions go* (for N elements there will generally be N-1 places to put them), as combinations - either with (if zero-size partitions are allowed) or without (otherwise) replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Case **without** repetition:

*Goal 1*: find words which characters belongs to different "sets". Each words is made out 10 character: w = c_1 ... c_10 such that each word contains 3 characters from both "sets".

*Goal 2*: find all possible permutations of such words

Data

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase # "set" 1
digits = string.digits            # "set" 2
```

Let a word be w = d_1...d_i a_1...a_j such that i+j=10 and i,j >= 3 where d's (digits) are the character of a "set", a's (alphabetic) of the other.

**Step 1**: possible values of (i, j)-pairs: the partitions of a word depends only on the amount elements of each set, not on the elements themselves. Equivalent to find all partition in 10 elements into two sets both with a size greater or equal to three:

```
N = 10 # size of a "word"
# constraints on the amounts of type of characters in a word
lower_bound1, lower_bound2 = 3, 3

def word_partitioner(list1, min1, list2, min2, word_length=10):
    # return pairs which entries represent the amount of characters to be used to form a word of length word_length
    # min1, min2 represents the lower bounds of the type of characters to be contained in the word
    return [(i, j) for i, j in product(range(min1, len(list1)), range(min2, len(list2))) if i + j == word_length]

partitions = word_partitioner(list1, lower_bound1, list2, lower_bound2, N)
print(partitions)
```

Output:

```
[(3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3)]
```

**Step 2**: each word of each set is unique up to a combinatorics quantity: there are *n choose k* words of length k out of n [NB also called binomial coefficient, nCk]:

out a partition (i, j) = (3, 7) on can assign 10C3 x 26C7 words of length 10 made of characters of both "sets".

**Step 3**: permutation of every character in the obtained words, makes each word unique up to a factorial of the word size N

(i, j) = (3, 7) --> 10C3 x 26C7 --> 10C3 x 26C7 * N!

```
     (3, 7)--> 78936000 --> 286442956800000
```

**Step 4**: iterate for every possible way to partition the word

```
import math
def words_stats(list1, n1, list2, n2):
    # return total amount of words per partition + print to screen info
    bin_prod = math.comb(len(list1), n1) * math.comb(len(list2), n2)
    fact = math.factorial(n1 + n2)
    tot = bin_prod * fact
    print(f'{len(list1)}C{n1} x {len(list2)}C{n2}  x ({n1+n2})! = {bin_prod} x {fact} = {tot}')
    return tot

print('Info:')
amount_of_possibilities = 0
for k1, k2 in partitions:
    amount_of_possibilities += words_stats(list1, k1, list2, k2)
print(f'Total possible words: {amount_of_possibilities}')
```

Output

```
Preliminar info:
10C3 x 26C7  x (10)! = 78936000 x 3628800 = 286442956800000
10C4 x 26C6  x (10)! = 48348300 x 3628800 = 175446311040000
10C5 x 26C5  x (10)! = 16576560 x 3628800 = 60153020928000
10C6 x 26C4  x (10)! = 3139500 x 3628800 = 11392617600000
10C7 x 26C3  x (10)! = 312000 x 3628800 = 1132185600000
Total possible words: 534567091968000
```

Make string (!!) of all possible words (recommended for small examples)

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations, product, 

def combinatorial_problem_formatter(list1, n1, list2, n2):
    # return table-like string of the possible words per partition
    print(f'Rows x Cols:  {len(list1)}C{n1} x {len(list2)}C{n2} x ({n1+n2})!')
    s = ''
    for pair1, pair2 in product(combinations(list1, n1), combinations(list2, n2)):
        for p in permutations(pair1 + pair2):
            s += ''.join(p) + ' '
        s += '\n'
    return s
```

**Toy model**:

set1: [0, 1, 3, 4] and
set2: [a, b, c, d]

Find words of length N=3 such contain at least 1 digits and 1 letter
w = c_1 c_2 c_3

```
N = 3 # size of a "word"

lower_bound1, lower_bound2 = 1, 1   # constraints on the amounts of type of characters in a word
list1, list2 = digits[:4], alphabet[:4]     # restrictions (for pedagogical reasons)
#

partitions = word_partitioner(list1, lower_bound1, list2, lower_bound2, N)
print('Partitions', partitions)

print('Preliminar info:')
amount_of_possibilities = 0
for k1, k2 in partitions:
    amount_of_possibilities += words_stats(list1, k1, list2, k2)
print(f'Total possible words: {amount_of_possibilities}')

print('='*40, '\n')

for k1, k2 in partitions:
    print(combinatorial_problem_formatter(list1, k1, list2, k2))
    print()
```

Output toy model

```
Partitions [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
Preliminar info:
4C1 x 4C2  x (3)! = 24 x 6 = 144
4C2 x 4C1  x (3)! = 24 x 6 = 144
Total possible words: 288
======================================== 

Rows x Cols:  4C1 x 4C2 x (3)!
0ab 0ba a0b ab0 b0a ba0 
0ac 0ca a0c ac0 c0a ca0 
0ad 0da a0d ad0 d0a da0 
0bc 0cb b0c bc0 c0b cb0 
0bd 0db b0d bd0 d0b db0 
0cd 0dc c0d cd0 d0c dc0 
1ab 1ba a1b ab1 b1a ba1 
1ac 1ca a1c ac1 c1a ca1 
1ad 1da a1d ad1 d1a da1 
1bc 1cb b1c bc1 c1b cb1 
1bd 1db b1d bd1 d1b db1 
1cd 1dc c1d cd1 d1c dc1 
2ab 2ba a2b ab2 b2a ba2 
2ac 2ca a2c ac2 c2a ca2 
2ad 2da a2d ad2 d2a da2 
2bc 2cb b2c bc2 c2b cb2 
2bd 2db b2d bd2 d2b db2 
2cd 2dc c2d cd2 d2c dc2 
3ab 3ba a3b ab3 b3a ba3 
3ac 3ca a3c ac3 c3a ca3 
3ad 3da a3d ad3 d3a da3 
3bc 3cb b3c bc3 c3b cb3 
3bd 3db b3d bd3 d3b db3 
3cd 3dc c3d cd3 d3c dc3 


Rows x Cols:  4C2 x 4C1 x (3)!
01a 0a1 10a 1a0 a01 a10 
01b 0b1 10b 1b0 b01 b10 
01c 0c1 10c 1c0 c01 c10 
01d 0d1 10d 1d0 d01 d10 
02a 0a2 20a 2a0 a02 a20 
02b 0b2 20b 2b0 b02 b20 
02c 0c2 20c 2c0 c02 c20 
02d 0d2 20d 2d0 d02 d20 
03a 0a3 30a 3a0 a03 a30 
03b 0b3 30b 3b0 b03 b30 
03c 0c3 30c 3c0 c03 c30 
03d 0d3 30d 3d0 d03 d30 
12a 1a2 21a 2a1 a12 a21 
12b 1b2 21b 2b1 b12 b21 
12c 1c2 21c 2c1 c12 c21 
12d 1d2 21d 2d1 d12 d21 
13a 1a3 31a 3a1 a13 a31 
13b 1b3 31b 3b1 b13 b31 
13c 1c3 31c 3c1 c13 c31 
13d 1d3 31d 3d1 d13 d31 
23a 2a3 32a 3a2 a23 a32 
23b 2b3 32b 3b2 b23 b32 
23c 2c3 32c 3c2 c23 c32 
23d 2d3 32d 3d2 d23 d32
```

NB: case with repetitions not implemented;
not explicit way to get a full list of words, just as a string version. To get a list/iterator of all such words modify the `combinatorial_problem_formatter` function keeping track of the already good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permutation of permutations?  If you need to allow each element in the list to repeat in the permutation, easiest might be to expand the list.  This looks like it would get enormous, however.

```
from itertools import product, permutations

def permutem(l1, l2, min_num=3, length=10):
    for n in range(min_num, length - min_num + 1):
        a, b = n, length - n
        for result in permutations(product(l1, r=a), product(l2, r=b)):
            yield result
```

Comment: What stand for max_e, min_e?

Comment: min and max number to permute from each list; edit to make this clear

Comment: @cards could be max elements and min elements, basically I think in this case it would be 3 as min and 7 as max since you have to have at least 3 from each list and a total of 10

Comment: thanks both! Ok, then is still open the partitioning of 10 subject to 3-3condition?

Comment: should be more clear, sorry; now it would take the length of the permutation you want an the minimum from each list.

Comment: Ok, seems nice... still on it

Comment: This looks much more elegant than mine. What python version is this? Complains about r is not a valid keyword for product and if I chane it to repeat, complains about Expected int as r.

Comment: the keyword of product is "repeat" not "r" (for python3)

Comment: @Drew E...could not run it, TypeError: 'r' is an invalid keyword argument for product(), just copy-paste the code

Comment: `r` is a keyword for `permutations`, not `product`. This code wasn't tested.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a more runtime efficient method of generating your values, but here's a space efficient implementation that has fairly straightforward logic:

```py
def valid_patterns(l1, l2, length=10, min_from_l1=3, min_from_l2=3):
    # use sets instead of lists as we're going to be calling `in` a lot below
    s1, s2 = set(l1), set(l2)

    # generate all possible patterns (combinations with replacement)
    for pattern in itertools.product(l1+l2, repeat=length):
        # check to see if the pattern is valid
        if sum(ch in s1 for ch in pattern) >= min_from_l1 and \
           sum(ch in s2 for ch in pattern) >= min_from_l2:
            yield pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# A Python program to print all
# permutations of given length
from itertools import permutations

# check_validity(tuple1) checks whether the combination contains at least 3 elements from list a and at least 3 elements from list b
def check_validity(tuple1):
    a_cnt = 0
    b_cnt = 0
    for t in tuple1:
        if t in a:
            a_cnt += 1
        if t in b:
            b_cnt += 1
    if a_cnt >= 3 and b_cnt>=3:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Get all permutations of length 10
a = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

list1 = a + b     # merge two lists
perm = list(permutations(list1, 10))     # find all permutaions

# Print the obtained permutations
result_perm = []
for tuple1 in perm:          # list of permutations contain tuples
    if check_validity(tuple1) == True:    # check_validity(tuple1) checks whether the combination contains at least 3 elements from list a and at least 3 elements from list b
        result_perm.append("".join(list(map(str,tuple1))))     # join characters from tuple to generate a string

result_perm
```