# Looping in python, Don't want getting the same result from the loop

Tags: python, nested-loops

Currently i'm studying data science, and really start this from zero
i'm trying to practice several things on Python right now

in this case i'm getting a category and should create a bundle

```
list_category = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10']
```

and in this context i want to get the result with this expectation:

a. not getting the same result in the bundle e.g `(c1,c1,c1)`
b. one bundle is allowed getting same two category e.g `(c1,c2,c1)`
c. same result with different order isn't allowed e.g (`c1 - c2 - c3 = c2 - c1 - c3)`

i tried to using this code, but apparently i'm still getting a lot of same result

```
list_category = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10']
bundling_list = []
for i in list_category:
   category1 = i
   for y in list_category:
       if i != y:
           category2 = y
           for c in list_category:
               if c != y:
                   category3 = c
                   bundling = i + '-' + y + '-' + c
               
               bundling_list.append(bundling)
               
print(bundling_list)
```

tried to google some, but i didn't get my expected answer so far, is there anyway to solve this
Thanks!

Comment: "and in this context i want to get the result with this expectation:" I can't understand your description of the problem at all. What is a "bundle"? How does the concept of a "bundle" relate to the output you want to have? For example, do you want to create a list of "bundles"? Can you show the *complete, exact* expected result for this specific input? If it's long, use a different value for `list_category` so that it's big enough to illustrate the desired behaviour, but still small enough to be workable.

Comment: That said, I think you should study more math or something. My guess is that you would be immediately able to find an answer for your problem with a search engine, if you simply *knew the proper names for things*.

Comment: So, are you trying to pick 3 random entries from your list, where you can have two repeats but not three?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes sir

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes sir 'bundles' in this context is the result that i expected

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68822603/all-permutations-from-2-lists-but-with-a-condition-on-the-amount-of-elements help?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes sir! thanks, actually its about probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import random module from python and use random.choice method to select a random item from your list.Then by creating a new list by avoiding that selected item.In this way 3 unique items can be collected from a list.

- You can also simply delete items chosen using random from the list thereby avoiding creation of 2 extra lists.

I Think This may help you :)

```
import random
list_category = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10']
l2=[]
l3=[]
n1=random.choice(list_category)
for i in list_category:
    if i!=n1:
        l2.append(i)
n2=random.choice(l2)
for i in l2:
    if i!=n2:
        l3.append(i)
n3=random.choice(l3)
bundle="-".join([n1,n2,n3])
print(bundle)
```