# How can I count sequences that meet these constraints?

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to count permutations of a sequence of `I` and `O` symbols, representing e.g. people entering (`I` for "in") and leaving (`O` for "out") a room. For a given `n` many `I` symbols, there should be exactly as many `O` symbols, giving a total length of `2*n` for the sequence. Also, at any point in a valid permutation, the number of `O` symbols must be less than or equal to the number of `I` symbols (since it is not possible for someone to leave the room when it is empty).

Additionally, I have some initial prefix of `I` and `O` symbols, representing people who previously entered or left the room. The output should only count sequences starting with that prefix.

For example, for `n=1` and an initial state of `''`, the result should be `1` since the only valid sequence is `IO`; for `n=3` and an initial state of `II`, the possible permutations are

```
IIIOOO
IIOIOO
IIOOIO
```

for a result of `3`. (There are five ways for three people to enter and leave the room, but the other two involve the first person leaving immediately.)

I'm guessing the simplest way to solve this is using `itertools.permutations`. This is my code so far:

```
n=int(input())  ##actual length will be 2*n
string=input()
I_COUNT=string.count("I")
O_COUNT=string.count("O")
if string[0]!="I":
 sys.exit()
if O_COUNT>I_COUNT:
 sys.exit()
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(string)]
print(perms)
```

the goal is to get the permutation for whatever is left out of the string and append it to the user's input, so how can I append user's input to the remaining length of the string and get the count for  permutation?

Comment: I am afraid I don't get the logic. For example, in ex1, why isn't "IIOOOI" one of the "permutations"? Why not "IIIIII"? Also, by "enter a desired portion of the string", do you mean that the input should be at the first part of each "permutation"?

Comment: Your "explanation" doesn't seem to tally with the sample input/output and your  code fragment doesn't use *n*. It's unclear (to me anyway) what *n* is used for

Comment: 2*n is the desired length of the string..

Comment: I see since it is "permutation", "IIIIII" would not make sense if it is to be an output with "IIIOOO". But _what_ do you "permute" in the first place? How can we tell if you are not permuting "IIIIII"?

Comment: possibility of "I" and "O" for the remaining of the string with the given conditions ..@j1-lee

Comment: @2020PythonNewby "IIIIII" satisfies the given condition: the number of O's is less than the number of I's, so does "IIIIIO" and "IIIIOO".

Comment: In `IO`, the number of `O` is not less than the number of `I` - same for the series including `IIIOOO`. Did you mean less than or equal? And why isn't `IIOOOI` not in that series? And you're implying the script only adds `O`s? Your problem seems very ill-defined and the question unclear.

Comment: @Grismar
fixed it it should be <=..

Comment: I tried to edit the question to express your idea more clearly, and directly [in the style we prefer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/kind-reminder-to-remove-noise). However, I still need your help. I can't make any sense out of your last paragraph; I think it has something to do with the approach you had in mind for solving the problem, but I can't quite grasp your thought process.

Comment: Second, it is unclear to me whether you actually need to *generate all the sequences* in order to consider the problem solved. Would you be satisfied by a solution that directly counts how many sequences there are, without creating them?

Comment: Now that you have included what `I` and `O` mean, the problem has become clearer. To me, the term "permutation" is confusing and misleading.

Comment: @j1-lee I did that, not OP. And it is only my inference, pending OP's confirmation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh I see!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I did explain what I and O are & you represented my idea in a better way (english is my 3rd language, sorry!)
and yes, I only need the count of possible sequence.

Comment: "I only need the count of possible sequence." I updated to reflect this, and also tried to make sure the answer is correct for the example inputs. (Unless there is some reason I don't understand, why e.g. `IOIOIO` is invalid?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I guess that's because the input was `II`, which is the "history"; it has already happened, i.e., two people have already entered. So a sequence must begin with `II`.

Comment: Oh, maybe I missed something about the problem statement, then.

Comment: yes, user already provide some part of the sequence and we need to fill the remaining.. @KarlKnechtel  :).. so the final answer is 3 not 5

Comment: Edited again, accordingly. I also can write an answer now.

Comment: thank you kind sir! :) now we wait for some clarity/answer :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel , Zack, J1-lee and others which i can't tag here
You guys are an inspiration; thank you very much for taking the time and  diligently explaining everything for me ! It will take years but I hope one day I get to your level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **product()** function from itertools will allow you to generate all the possible sequences of 'I' and 'O' for a given length.

From that list, you can filter by the sequences that start with the user-supplied `start_seq`.

From that list, you can filter by the sequences that are valid, given your rules of the number and order of the 'I's and 'O's:

```py
from itertools import product


def is_valid(seq):
    '''Evaluates a sequence I's and O's following the rules that:
        - there cannot be more outs than ins
        - the ins and outs must be balanced
    '''
    _in, _out = 0, 0
    for x in seq:
        if x == 'I':
            _in += 1
        else:
            _out += 1

        if (_out > _in) or (_in > len(seq)/2):
            return False

    return True


# User inputs...
start_seq = 'II'

assert start_seq[0] != 'O', 'Starting sequence cannot start with an OUT.'

n = 3
total_len = n*2

assert len(start_seq) < total_len, 'Starting sequence is at least as big as total number, nothing to iterate.'

# Calculate all possible sequences that are total_len long, as tuples of 'I' and 'O'
seq_tuples = product('IO', repeat=total_len)

# Convert tuples to strings, e.g., `('I', 'O', 'I')` to `'IOI'`
sequences = [''.join(seq_tpl) for seq_tpl in seq_tuples]

# Filter for sequences that start correctly
sequences = [seq for seq in sequences if seq.startswith(start_seq)]

# Filter for valid sequences
sequences = [seq for seq in sequences if is_valid(seq)]

print(sequences)
```

and I get:

```py
['IIIOOO', 'IIOIOO', 'IIOOIO']
```

Comment: so this is specifically for the case if the string starts with II, correct? in actual scenario  , it depends on the user's input which could be anything.. how do we fit that here?

Comment: I've rethought how to approach this, and found the `product()` func in itertools that basically does what my own function did, so I swapped out my custom code for the standard library. And, I refactored my sequence validator. I hope you can see now how to integrate these ideas into your program. Cheers!

Comment: so I implemented your approach and for a longer string I get memory limit exceeded and tried to improve it a bit and now I get time limit exceeded lol..is there a way to make this more efficient ? 

this is what i replaced:
count=0
for items in seq_tuples:
    seq_tuples=''.join(items)
    if seq_tuples.startswith(start_seq) and is_valid(items):
        count+=1

Comment: How big of a string/long of a sequence?

Comment: 30 characters is the max

Comment: These built functions  do return the right sequence but from a time & memory perspective they can be problematic with large inputs eg. n=10 & prefix string=IIIIIIIIII;    "eq_tuples = product('IO', repeat=total_len)" calculate all the possibilities and then we filter out what we want 
( is_valid() & seq.statswith() ) . I'm surprised that even though  the product function executes recursively but still faces memory & time limit for large cases.. so I came up with a solution(see my answer) and with that I am not hitting any memory/time limits -- but your code put me to the right direction :)

Comment: Super glad it helped, but I'm even happier to see it inspired you and worked out something better for yourself 

Comment: This leaves me questioning, though, what are your "limits"? Are they practical? I ran your `n=10` and prefix `string='IIIIIIIIIII'` example: mine ran in .5s and yours in .04s. A 10x speed is awesome! But... why is 1/2 second too slow? And memory... 2**10 is 1 million strings at 20 bytes each, I can see 20 MB seeming egregious for this, but I've got 16GB memory of my laptop (wow, computers, these days).

Comment: so the data is landing into an MPP Datawarehouse  & some bucketing happens on the air as well and most importantly these clients have CRAZY SLAs....we are building the pipeline and I am pretty sure there will be more challenges on the road

Comment: Wow! Yeah, I asked those questions because I'm genuinely curious what constraints you're facing... but also because of an over-tendency towards "efficiency", that I see on SO, and that I still deal with in myself. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
@cache
def count_permutations(ins: int, outs: int):
    # ins and outs are the remaining number of ins and outs to process
    assert outs >= ins
    if ins == 0 :
        # Can do nothing but output "outs"
        return 1
    elif outs == ins:
        # Your next output needs to be an I else you become unbalanced
        return count_permutations(ins - 1, outs)
    else:
        # Your. next output can either be an I or an O
        return count_permutations(ins - 1, outs) + count_permutations(ins, outs - 1)
```

If, say you have a total of 5 Is and 5 Os, and you've already output one I, then you want:  `count_permutations(4, 5)`.

Comment: `cache` isn't a builtin last I checked. Are you thinking of e.g. `functools.lru_cache`?

Comment: The `@cache` decorator was introduced in Python 3.9.  `@lru_cache` has been available since 3.2.

Comment: Yep, just looked it up. I have been waiting for even-numbered minor versions to update, out of laziness... but 3.10 is out, so I need to get on that :)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm guessing the simplest way to solve this is using itertools.permutations

Sadly, this will not be very helpful. The problem is that `itertools.permutations` does not care about the value of the elements it's permuting; it treats them as all distinct regardless. So if you have 6 input elements, and ask for length-6 permutations, you will get 720 results, even if all the inputs are the same.

`itertools.combinations` has the opposite issue; it doesn't distinguish *any* elements. When it selects some elements, it only puts those elements in the order they initially appeared. So if you have 6 input elements and ask for length-6 combinations, you will get 1 result - the original sequence.

Presumably what you wanted to do is generate all the distinct ways of arranging the `I`s and `O`s, then take out the invalid ones, then count what remains. This is possible, and the `itertools` library [can help with the first step, but it is not straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68822603/all-permutations-from-2-lists-but-with-a-condition-on-the-amount-of-elements).

It will be simpler to use a recursive algorithm directly. The general approach is as follows:

- At any given time, we care about how many people are in the room and how many people must still enter. To handle the prefix, we simply count how many people are in the room right now, and subtract that from the total number of people in order to determine how many must still enter. I leave the input handling as an exercise.
- To determine that count, we count up the ways that involve the next action being `I` (someone comes in), plus the ways that involve the next action being `O` (someone leaves).
- If everyone has entered, there is only one way forward: everyone must leave, one at a time. This is a base case.
- Otherwise, it is definitely possible for someone to come in. We recursively count the ways for everyone else to enter *after* that; in the recursive call, there is one more person in the room, and one fewer person who must still enter.
- If there are still people who have to enter, *and* there is also someone in the room right now, then it is also possible for someone to leave first. We recursively count the ways for others to enter after that; in the recursive call, there is one fewer person in the room, and the same number who must still enter.

This translates into code fairly directly:

```py
def ways_to_enter(currently_in, waiting):
    if waiting == 0:
        return 1
    result = ways_to_enter(currently_in + 1, waiting - 1)
    if currently_in > 0:
        result += ways_to_enter(currently_in - 1, waiting)
    return result
```

Some testing:

```
>>> ways_to_enter(0, 1) # n = 1, prefix = ''
1
>>> ways_to_enter(2, 1) # n = 3, prefix = 'II'; OR e.g. n = 4, prefix = 'IIOI'
3
>>> ways_to_enter(0, 3) # n = 3, prefix = ''
5
>>> ways_to_enter(0, 14) # takes less than a second on my machine
2674440
```

We can improve the performance for larger values by decorating the function with [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) (`lru_cache` prior to 3.9), which will [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) results of the previous recursive calls. The more purpose-built approach is to use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) techniques: in this case, we would initialize 2-dimensional storage for the results of `ways_to_enter(x, y)`, and compute those values one at a time, in such a way that the values needed for the "recursive calls" have already been done earlier in the process.

That direct approach would look something like:

```
def ways_to_enter(currently_in, waiting):
    # initialize storage
    results = [[0] * currently_in for _ in waiting]
    # We will iterate with `waiting` as the major axis.
    for w, row in enumerate(results):
        for c, column in enumerate(currently_in):
            if w == 0:
                value = 1
            else:
                value = results[w - 1][c + 1]
                if c > 0:
                    value += results[w][c - 1]
            results[w][c] = value
    return results[-1][-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a dynamic programming problem.

Given the number of in and out operations remaining, we do one of the following:

1. If we're out of either ins or outs, we can only use operations of the other type. There is only one possible assignment.
2. If we have an equal number of ins or outs, we must use an in operation according to the constraints of the problem.
3. Finally, if we have more ins than outs, we can perform either operation. The answer, then, is the sum of the number of sequences if we choose to use an in operation plus the number of sequences if we choose to use an out operation.

This runs in `O(n^2)` time, although in practice the following code snippet can be made faster using a 2D-list rather than the cache annotation (I've used `@cache` in this case to make the recurrence easier to understand).

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def find_permutation_count(in_remaining, out_remaining):
    if in_remaining == 0 or out_remaining == 0:
        return 1
    elif in_remaining == out_remaining:
        return find_permutation_count(in_remaining - 1, out_remaining)
    else:
        return find_permutation_count(in_remaining - 1, out_remaining) + find_permutation_count(in_remaining, out_remaining - 1)
    
print(find_permutation_count(3, 3)) # prints 5
```

Comment: is cache supported in 3.8? for some reason I am getting "cannot import name 'cache' from functools" error

Comment: No, it was introduced in 3.9. Use `@lru_cache` if you have a lower Python version.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant perhaps but this certainly seems to fulfil the brief:

```
from itertools import permutations

def isvalid(start, p):
    for c1, c2 in zip(start, p):
        if c1 != c2:
            return 0
    n = 0
    for c in p:
        if c == 'O':
            if (n := n - 1) < 0:
                return 0
        else:
            n += 1
    return 1

def calc(n, i):
    s = i + 'I' * (n - i.count('I'))
    s += 'O' * (n * 2 - len(s))
    return sum(isvalid(i, p) for p in set(permutations(s)))

print(calc(3, 'II'))
print(calc(3, 'IO'))
print(calc(3, 'I'))
print(calc(3, ''))
```

**Output:**

```
3
2
5
5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def solve(string,n):
  countI =string.count('I')
  if countI==n:
    return 1
  countO=string.count('O')
  if countO > countI:
    return 0
  k= solve(string + 'O',n)
  h= solve(string + 'I',n)
  return k+h

n= int(input())
string=input()
print(solve(string,n))
```

Comment: so as I explained under Zach's approach the problem with the built-in function is that it calculates all the possibilities (2^n times..i think?) and then we somehow need to force the filtering of our desire. with this approach we are calculating and  & filtering at the same time(recursively) and therefor didn't face the time & memory limit exception  for larger inputs.
but again his approach led me to the right direction and I appreciate his and everybody else contribution to this!! BIG thank you !!
this was a great learning experience for sure !

Answer (score 0):

The number of such permutations of length `2n` is given by the `n`'th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). Wikipedia gives a formula for Catalan numbers in terms of central binomial coefficients:

```
from math import comb

def count_permutations(n):
  return comb(2*n,n) // (n+1)

for i in range(1,10):
  print(i, count_permutations(i))

# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 5
# 4 14
# 5 42
# 6 132
# 7 429
# 8 1430
# 9 4862
```